# Doctrine JOIN syntax

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, inner-join

I'm having an issue converting some legacy SQL for the doctrine query builder. I think the problem is in the inner join, but I can't quite work out the parameters the builder is expecting.

This is what I have so far:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('ob.size', 'ob.colour', 'ob.productId', 'p.title')
            ->from('m:Option', 'ob')
            ->innerJoin('m:Product', 'p', 'ON', 'ob.ProductId');
```

And this is the original query:

```
 query="select size,colour,product_id,title from
                products,options_new where
                picture = '' and
                products.id = options_new.product_id and
                product_id like 'UTRW%'
                group by product_id";
```

I normally write joins explicitly, so I'm not certain I'm understanding how the from clause is working here.

At the moment the new query is generating this error:

> Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'

Cheers!

Comment: ->innerJoin('m:Product', 'p', 'WITH', 'ob.ProductId=p.id');

Comment: @websky That worked perfectly :) I would upvote, but I don't have the points/repution

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below (drop here your entities, would be more helpful) and for more details about fetching related entities, check the docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb->select('ob.size', 'ob.colour', 'ob.productId', 'p.title')
    ->innerJoin('m.product', 'ob');
```